# How to calculate the outward flux of a vector field through a cone?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

Let $R$ be a region in the plane, and let $P$ be a point at a height $h$ above the plane.  Form a cone by drawing lines from $P$ to each point on the boundary of $R$, and define a vector field by $x \Bbb i + y \Bbb j + z \Bbb k$.  Denote $D$ as the region in space that is bounded above by the cone, and bounded below by $R$.

Show that the outward flux of the vector field through the boundary of $D$ is $hA$, where $A$ is the area of $R$.

In addition, use the divergence theorem to show that $D$'s volume is $\dfrac {\pi r^2} 3$.

Comment: What is $r$ in $\pi r^2/3$?

Comment: I think the OP wants to prove that D's volume is $\frac{hA}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

By the divergence theorem, the flux equals

$$
\phi=\iiint_E \nabla \cdot \vec{F}\; dV = 3 V(E),
$$

and since $E$ is a cone with basis $A$ and height $h$:
$$
\phi = 3 V(E)=3 \frac{A h}{3}=Ah.
$$